# Command line arguments not being passed in sbatch

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, slurm

I am trying to submit a job using the SLURM job scheduler and am finding that when I use the `--export=VAR=VALUE` syntax then some of my variables are not being passed (often the variable in the first instance of `export`). My understanding is that I need to specify `--export=...` for each variable, e.g.

```
sbatch --export=build=true --export=param=p100_256 run.py
```

My script "run.py" looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import os,fnmatch

print(os.environ["SLURM_JOB_NAME"])
print(os.environ["SLURM_JOB_ID"])

print(fnmatch.filter(os.environ.keys(),"b*"))
print(fnmatch.filter(os.environ.keys(),"p*"))
```

I'd prefer to submit a python script as all of my existing scripts (used previously with PBS) are already in python and I don't want to have to rewrite them in shell scripts. My problem is best demonstrated through a short example.

Firstly,

```
> sbatch --export=build=true --export=param=p100_256 run.py
> Submitted batch job 2249581
```

produces a log file with the following:

```
run.py
2249581
[]
['param']
```

If I reverse the order of the `export` flags for 'build' and 'param',

```
> sbatch --export=param=true --export=build=p100_256 run.py
> Submitted batch job 2249613
```

then the log file now looks like,

```
run.py
2249613
['build']
[]
```

which would suggest that only the final instance of the `export` flag is being passed. If I add in a third instance of `export`,

```
 > sbatch --export=param=1 --export=build=p100_256 --export=build_again=hello  run.py
 > Submitted batch job 2249674
```

then the log file returns,

```
run.py
2249674
['build_again']
[]
```

So does anybody know why only the final instance of `export` is being passed? Have I got the syntax incorrect? Do I need to specify an additional flag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, looks like I had the syntax incorrect. I missed in the documentation that additional variables should be comma separated and specified with a  single `export` flag, e.g.

```
> sbatch --export=build=true,param=p100_256 run.py
```

So previous instances of `export` must be being replaced each time `export` is specified.